# Intuition for trigonometric function of complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How can I intuitively understand trigonometric functions on a complex angle like what does $\cos(\theta)$ even mean when $\theta$ is complex. How can I represent this as I would have done showing a circle of radius $R$ whose any point can be represented as $P (R \cos(\theta), R \sin(\theta)) $ if $\theta$ would have been real.

Comment: In a case like this, I would recommend trying not for intuition, but for experience. That is, work out some examples. Make sure you can see that even for complex $\theta$, you get the relation $\cos\theta=\cos(\theta+2\pi)$.

Comment: @VishalGoyal Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can refer to the expression obtained by Euler's formula

$$\cos \theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$$

but of course we can't visualize that function on the complex plane in a easy way such as for the circle in the real case.

What we can do is to plot a surface for $\operatorname{Re}(\cos \theta)$, $\operatorname{Im}(\cos \theta)$ or $|\cos \theta|$ to obtain the following [**plots**](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/visualizations/5/).

Comment: +1 for giving the link for plots

Comment: @VishalGoyal Thanks but I think you can't upvote since you rep is not enough!